# Node module giving no output - have I misunderstood how to install it?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to install and run the `geo2topo` node module, as described here:
https://github.com/topojson/topojson-server#command-line-reference

When I run it, I basically get no output - even -h gives no response, and no warnings or errors:

```
$ geo2topo -h
$ geo2topo -V
```

I'm familiar with Linux sysadmin but not very familiar with node.

I've done (on a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS box):

```
$ sudo apt-get install node npm
$ sudo npm install topojson-server
```

as per:
https://github.com/topojson/topojson-server#installing

I've verified that it does seem to be present:

```
$ which geo2topo
/usr/local/bin/geo2topo
```

and that the dependencies seem to be present:

```
$ npm -g ls
/usr/local/lib
└─┬ topojson-server@3.0.0
  └── commander@2.11.0
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: not sure if this solves your issue but may be worth a try: have you installed http://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=nodejs-legacy, maybe the script isnt executed without the right symlink to node

Comment: @JohannesMerz Thank you - that seems to have fixed it. (It's most confusing that no output is given!) Please do add that as a solution and I'll accept, to ensure you get the reputation points.

Comment: done, glad 2 help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install nodejs-legacy
https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=nodejs-legacy

Otherwise the package doesnt get the right symlink to node.